# Upload images asynchronously on TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

If I paste a bunch of images on tinymce and then use the `uploadImages` method, then I get tens of progress popups showing the synchronous upload of images one by one. Which is slow and quite unnatural?

Is there any way to upload all images at the same time? Asynchronously?

[image]